# Godaddy cloud server root login permission denied

Tags: ssh, cloud, root

I have Cloud Hosting in godaddy.

We have Create one cloud server in this hosting and install ubuntu 16.04. After that server create successfully. Then After i have try to root login using ssh. it's not working always say **permission denied.**

I have also add my PC public key in **ssh key** Section. but root login not working.

**Error : Permission denied, please try again.**

Any Why the root login not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found two solutions:

1. Destroy The current server and setup new server.
2. Go to Godaddy Setting option > Console

   - Try to login with single user mode.
   - Set harddisk in read/write mode
   - Reset password

I suggest to try the first option